# using common virtualenvs on dropbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a project where the code lives on a shared dropbox (not my choice, I can't change this.) In windows, the users all mount the dropbox in `c:/Dropbox`. On Macs, they all mount in `~/Dropbox` (not my choice, I can't change this.)

In Python 2, the windows users used a common venv that lived on the dropbox. I was able to make it relocatable with the --relocatable option, and the few mac users just made their own venvs.

In Python3, I have more Mac users, so I want to have relocatable venvs for everyone. However, the Windows doesn't seem to work right, and the mac one doesn't seem to work at all.

The structure I want is to have `Dropbox/venvs/[mac, win]` and have virtualenvs in the appropriate directories. and have people use the appropriate venvs.

I already have systems in place for the users to automatically access the correct venv. However, the venvs don't work correctly on any machine other than the one that they were created on, because of all of the hard-coding.

What is the "correct" way to deal with this? I don't think that I'm trying to solve THAT weird of a problem, and virtualenv doesn't make my solution easy, so I figure that there should be some other accepted architecture for this... what is it?

Comment: The venv's have problem because a venv's contains executable files, this is not a problem for Windows, since it allows executing of all files, but in Linux and Mac, this is signalled by file permissions, something Dropbox does not sync. This means that the envs only work when running locally

Comment: I don't understand. The problem doesn't have to do with permissions. The permissions are fine. The problem is pythonpath stuff.